# Why can't ping via interface in java code?

Tags: android

After setuping two network interface wlan0 and rmnet_data0, I hope ping some IP or website via one of them in java code.
The cmd is `ping -I rmnet_data0 <websiteURL>`. It works well by inputing to adb shell. But it can't work in android java code. I try to test it in native or jni. Still failure.

Java code like:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pingCmdString);

int result = p.waitFor();
```

After running, the result is 2. The apk is system uid.
Any one can help on it?

Comment: What happens when this is done via `adb shell` ?

Comment: @MarkKeen run it in adb root mode:

pollux:/ # ping -c 1 -I rmnet_data0 www.stackoverflow.com
PING stackoverflow.com (151.101.65.69) from 10.60.219.49 rmnet_data0: 56(84) byt
es of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.65.69: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=246 ms

--- stackoverflow.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 246.187/246.187/246.187/0.000 ms